# Make WPF Trigger use any Property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, datagrid, styles

I use a `Datagrid`. In that I put a List of `Area` like that:

```
ObservableCollection<Area> areas = new ObservableCollection<Area>();
...
datagrid.ItemsSource = areas;
```

Now I want to set the style of the rows according to a property of an `Area`.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <!-- Compiler can't find UseForGroups -->
         <Trigger Property="Area.UseForGroups" Value="True">  
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

How can I reference to `Area.UseForGroups`?

### EDIT

I tried the following with `DataTriggers` but nothing happens

```
<DataGrid ...>
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseForGroups}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using a DataTrigger

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseForGroups}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>


<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" ...>
```

Note that you shouldn't specify 'Area.UseForGroups' just 'UseForGroups' since the DataContext for an individual row is an *Area*.

Comment: Can we see the Area class?  Does it have a property UseForGroups, and does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. Didn't set the Property correctly. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `DataTrigger`?

EDIT:

A regular `Trigger` responds to dependency properties (normally GUI properties).

A `DataTrigger` can respond to any .NET property (by setting its Binding property).

EDIT 2:

Also I think using a `DataTrigger` you don't need to specify `Area.UseForGroups` only `UseForGroups` because the binding for you `DataGridRow` is already of type `Area`